# Retrieving and displaying MongoDB document content in Laravel 4 with Jenssegers Laravel library

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4, jenssegers-mongodb

I am new to Laravel. I am using the Jenssegers Laravel library, an eloquent model and query builder with support for MongoDB.

In my database, I created the document below. I am trying to show on the browser the content of the document but I am not successful.

I'd appreciate some hints or help on how to retrieve and display the content of a MongoDB document on Laravel 4.

Thanks.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("537124d584142189174ce113"),
"username" : "usertest",
"password" : "passtest",
"email" : "test@email.com",
"school" : "College university",
"country" : "USA",
"state" : "Washington",
"city" : "Seattle"
}
```

This is the code I got down so far..

File: /app/models/User.php

```
<?php
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;


class User extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The database table (collection) used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $collection = 'user';

     $users = User::all();

     public function all()
     {
        return $this->$users;
     }
}
```

File: /app/routes.php

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
return View::make('users')->with('user',$users);

});
```

File: /app/views/users.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <p>{{ $user->name }}</p>
    @endforeach
@stop
```

File: /app/views/layout.blade.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Laravel Quickstart</h1>

        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have to define "all function" in your model it's already defiend in Eloquent. Also Mongo library is working similar. So , try to use "User::all()" in your Controller or Route. You can directly print it. I suggest you to check it first Eloquent Documentation http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is obvious, but if you wan to use `users` variable in view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
// some code
@endforeach
```

then in route (or controller) you should you should pass `users` not `user`:

```
// should be
return View::make('users')->with('users',$users);

// not    
return View::make('users')->with('user',$users);
```

Also I would rather put User::all() in route/controller then in model, because like mentioned in comment by Muharrem Tigdemir - it is already declared in Eloquent. It would look something like this:

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    return View::make('users')->with('user', User::all());

});
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In your document you have `username`, but in the users.blade.php file you are referencing `<p>{{ $user->name }}</p>`

It should be `<p>{{ $user->username }}</p>`